# How to order by multiple columns with propel

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

I need to sort a query by 2 columns. Is this possible using propel?

i tried:

```
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::COL1);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::COL2);
```

but the second call to addAscendingOrderByColumn overrides the first one.

Regards,
Radu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are using Propel 1.4 (Symfony 1.4), it seems that you will have to switch to raw SQL there...

No answer in the (old) Symfony forum : http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/90447/

However, since Propel 1.5 it should work with the new syntax (Doctrine style). It's not detailed in Propel doc but when I test this, it works (gives `ORDER BY author.name ASC, author.id DESC`).

```
$authors = AuthorQuery::create()
  ->orderByName()
  ->orderById('desc')
  ->find();
```

Maybe consider upgrading to Propel 1.5.

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with this issue and after reading this post I have been almost gave up... but suddendly I found this solution:

```
$criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ClassPeer::COLUMN1)->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ClassPeer::COLUMN2);
```

In this way the second call to addAscendingOrderByColumn will add the order to the first one.