# How to get the next record that is greater than or equal to the current one in symfony?

Tags: php, sql, symfony-1.4, propel

Here's my code:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE);
$c->add(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE, $item->getItemDate(), Criteria::GREATER_THAN);
$this->next = ItemPeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

This works fine except when multiple dates are the same, for example: 3/1/2013 and 3/1/2013

When this happens it doesn't select the next one. For example (sorted by date):

```
Apple     2/27/2013
Banana    2/28/2013
Kiwi      3/1/2013
Dolphin   3/1/2013
ICBM      3/1/2013
```

If the current item is `Banana`, the next one will be correctly chosen as `Kiwi`. However, if the current item is `Kiwi`, it will be unable to find the next one. I'd like it to always choose the next one in date, even if the next date is the same. How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be asking the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147694/how-to-retrieve-the-next-item-in-a-list-of-mysql-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Criteria::GREATER_EQUAL` instead of `Criteria::GREATER_THAN`

EDIT: Ah, I see your problem now, you should [add a second ordering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584484/how-to-order-by-multiple-columns-with-propel). Perhaps use the primary key as the second criteria, so you get a consistent ordering, then use the second ordering to determine the next item. Basically, you need the equivalent of `select ... from ... where (item_date > mydate) or (item_date = mydate and id > myid) order by date, id asc` in symfony.

EDIT2:

```
$c = new Criteria();
// [item.item_date > $item->getItemDate()]
$crit0 = $c->getNewCriterion(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE, $item->getItemDate(), Criteria::GREATER_THAN);
// [item.item_date = $item->getItemDate()]
$crit1 = $c->getNewCriterion(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE, $item->getItemDate());
// [item.id > $item->id]
$crit2 = $c->getNewCriterion(ItemPeer::ID, $item->getId(), Criteria::GREATER_THAN);

// [item.item_date = $item->getItemDate()] *AND* [item.id > $item->getId()]
$crit1->addAnd($crit2);

// [item.item_date > $item->getItemDate()] *OR* [[item.item_date = $item->getItemDate()] AND [item.id > $item->getId()]]
$crit0->addOr($crit1);

$c->add($crit0);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ItemPeer::ID);

$this->next = ItemPeer::doSelectOne($c);
```

Comment: That was my first thought and I tried it but it just sets `$next` to the current `$item` every time. So if I was on `Banana`, with `GREATER_EQUAL` it sets `$next` to `Banana`.

Comment: I tried something like this but it didn't seem to fix it: `$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ItemPeer::ITEM_ID)->addAscendingOrderByColumn(ItemPeer::ITEM_DATE);` I tried `GREATER_EQUAL` and `GREATER_THAN`, as well as sorting by `DATE` and then `ID`

Comment: @JohnSmith: unfortunately, I don't know enough about Propel to do this off the top of my head, try something like the code I've added above.